# What does 撒回 mean in 部分领导人撒回祝贺，一些领导人则保持沉默?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading a newspaper article about the US election, and in the context of Trump's early claim of his election success, it describes the time Bush Jr's election was called early:

> [image: screenshot of 美国大选计票出现“过山车”]

In particular I'm confused about:

> 部分领导人**撒回**祝贺，一些领导人则保持沉默。
> <sub>*美国大选计票出现“过山车”*，环球时报，2020年11月5日</sub>

I'm unclear on what 撒回 means here; it seems something like "retract", in the sense of: leaders retract their (premature) congratulations.  But I'm not sure.

**Question**: What does 撒回 mean in 部分领导人撒回祝贺，一些领导人则保持沉默?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 撤退 = retreat; 撤回 = redraw / retract

撤回前言 (retract the previous words)

撤回祝贺 (retract the congratulations)

*撤回 is a formal term for retracting a formal statement*

Comment: Ooh!  It's a different character!  (撤回 not 撒回)

Answer (score 1):

It should be 撤回, not 撒回.

It means to do the reverse action of a specific action, e.g. undo, unsend, retract, pull back, roll back.

> 部分领导人**撤回**祝贺，一些领导人则保持沉默。
>
> Some leaders **unsend** their congratulations, while some leaders keep silence.